# Need suggestions regarding installation of a hand shower with an old style water mixer.

Tags: bathroom, shower, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I would like to keep the current water mixer as it is, and install the hand shower without getting into the hassle of destroying the wall. I am looking for an aesthetic approach to it.
[image: current water faucet]

I have to implement this in twenty two bathrooms. Can somebody suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The nuts leading to the mixing valve is what is keeping it on the pipes. Undo those (after shutting off the water) and the mixing valve will come off.

Then you can install a new tap assembly. There are models that come with a diverter where a shower can be attached to. Those are often used for bathtubs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a cost effective solution so as to keep the current arrangement and install a wall mixer for the hand shower to the same pipelines that is connected to this mixer.

Comment: Bulk buying 2 dozen bathtub mixer taps with shower hose and spending a day or two installing them is going to be the most cost efficient method IMO.

Comment: I will keep in mind, makes sense, thank you so much

Comment: Do you need to have the thermostatic function (anti-scald function)? Is the hot water in this building hot enough (= or > 50 C = 120 F) to cause scalding? Are you legally required to have anti-scald function?

Answer (score 0):

That is an "external mixing valve" the advantage of which is that the wall does not have to be opened up to change the entire mixing valve. Look on youtube for videos showing installation of external mixing valves.

The usual expected spacing for the supply lines for an external mixing valve is 15 cm  (about 6 inches). Is that what you have?

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll look into it. Can you share some link to some sample product so that i know what exactly to look for

Comment: One more thing, i want to keep the current mixer as well, and i need to attach the external wall mixer separately

Comment: How cheaply do you want to do get a showering capability? If you don't need to use the tub as a tub, you could probably screw a fitting into the spout and connect a hand held shower to that.

Comment: As cheap as possible, i was thinking if there can be some t-joint kind of solution which looks aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: If you want to keep the existing valve, but want to retain the ability to deliver water from the spout, you could screw a diverter into the spout and attach a hose to a handheld shower to that. A new mixer valve will have a thermostatic feature which prevents scalding, but at a cost. https://usa.hudsonreed.com/showers/exposed-shower-valves

Comment: Use a mirror to see if there are threads in the end of the spout. You may have to unscrew an "aerator/filter". Some old tub spouts in the US did have threads and I once retrofitted a shower in one of these by threading in a short length of pipe and then fitting a neoprene hose over it to a shower mounted on the wall. we lose the function of delivering water out of the spout. But this was of course reversible.

Comment: Thank you so much, the last suggestion makes a lot of sense